# Down voting and my reputation

Tags: support

If I down vote someone else's answer, does my reputation loose a point too? I'm asking this because in my updates I can the see "-1 down voting"

If true can some explain to me rational behind this please.

Comment: Yay! Tumbleweed achievement lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1 reputation on downvotes is standard behaviour across all SE sites. See [Privileges - Voting Down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: Is it cause people to limit their use of downvotes to be more sparing?

Comment: I think it's to encourage people to downvote responsibly. I have read a rationale posted by SE for this, but can't find it now.